# Output is in reverse order

Tags: binary

I wrote a simple decimal to binary conversion program. if input in given let say 58 and 23 it converts it into 010111 and 111010 respectively but 58 is equal to 111010 and 23 is equal to 10111.Basically it is giving answer in reverse order. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
        int a,b,bin1,bin2;
        cout<<"Enter First Integer(must be last 2 digit of arid number) : ";
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Enter Second Integer(any number between 1-100) : ";
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"First Binary Conversion : ";
        while (a>0)
        {
             bin1 = a % 2;
            cout << bin1;
            a /= 2;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Second Binary Conversion : ";
        while (b>0)
        {
            bin2 = b % 2;
            cout << bin2;
            b /= 2;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it reversed because it iterates from the last digit. To reverse it you can put bin1 and bin2 into some king od array and then reverse it.

example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    bool arr[32];

    cout << "Dec: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
    }

    cout << "Bin = ";

    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) // prints form the last digit
        cout << arr[j];
}
```

Comment: Of course if you want binary number to be simple in use you should reverse first